# Selecting row from excel column and generating new column based on the other column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new on Python.
I have and excel data. I import it in Python. And I want to some changes on it. For example I have some columns and I want to have it filtered some row of columns that I define and according to these rows it will write a new property to other column. Just for  well understanding  I have;

```
A       B      C 
1    red       -
3    white     -
2    white     -
3    pink      -
2    blue      -
```

For example if `df.['A']=2` and `df.['B']=='blue'`  , it will write 'a1' to the corresponding line on C column   and this way , I will complete my C column the way that I want. How can I do that?
Thank you for your answers..

Answer (score 3):

use pandas
https://pandas.pydata.org/

```
import pandas as pd 

dataset = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
dataset.loc[(dataset['A'] == 2) & (dataset['B'] == 'blue') ,'C'] = 'a1'
dataset.to_excel('test1.xlsx')
```